# Face tracking issue in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, face-detection

I'm new to opencv and I was working with colors , thresholds at the beginning and stepped forward to face tracking. Here is the code I have written to implement the face tracking rectangle with the input of my web cam. The problem is the size of the vector filled by the "face_cascade.detectMultiScale" goes to a huge number, resulting an Unhandled exception.

I have included all the libraries and cascade xml files and I don't see any fault I have done. For easy debugging I added a cout after the multiscale method call.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //creating the classifier object used for the face detection
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

//use the haarcascade_frontface_alt.xml library
face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml");

//setup camera
VideoCapture captureDevice;
captureDevice.open(0);

//setup image files used in the capture process
Mat capFrame;
Mat grayscaleFrame;

//create a window to present the results
namedWindow("output", 1);

//create a loop to capture and find the faces 
while (true)
{
    //capture a new image frame
    captureDevice >> capFrame;

    //convert captured Image to grayscale and equalize
    cvtColor(capFrame, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(grayscaleFrame, grayscaleFrame);

    //create a vector array to store the faces found
    std::vector<Rect> faces;

    //find faces and store them in the vector array
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    cout << faces.size();

    //draw a rectangle on the face

        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
            Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);

            rectangle(capFrame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
        }


    //print the output
    imshow("output", capFrame);

    //pause for 33 ms
    waitKey(33);
}

return 0;
}
```

So the output on the console (by the cout) is :

```
4292486918
```

I have followed many tutorials on face tracking and everything is similar to this. This is the simplest and even that doesn't work.
p.s : don't worry about the xml file. I have tried with all the xml files and It can't be an issue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: first, try the most simple thing on earth: `cout << faces.size() << endl;` ( put each detection on a single line ;) then, try to increase the 'minNeighbours' param to weed out more false detections: `face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 5, ...) `

Comment: oops for the typo, well that doesn't help either.

Comment: at least it helps to clear, how many actual detections there are per frame. now, i do not think, the error is in your code, rather in the way you link your program on win. please do a triple check, if you're strictly linking release libs(check all of them) for a release build, and debug libs for debug.